# Create DM to user and wait for response

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to use discord.py to create a DM to a specific user, and when they respond, it sends their message back to me in DMs. How would I do that? I have tried to search, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include your code, approaches and errors you face. You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `wait_for`

```py
@bot.command()
async def dm_user(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    try:
        await member.send('Hi yo have 30 seconds to respond')
    except discord.HTTPException:
        await ctx.send('unable to message')
    else: 
        try:
            msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check = lambda x: x.channel == member.dm_channel and x.author == member, timeout=30)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send('timed out')
        finally:
            await ctx.author.send(msg.content)
```

### References:

- [DMChannel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.DMChannel)
- [HTTPException](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.HTTPException)
- [more info on wait_for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66641673/12451222)