# Is there a way to make it such that the user must answer within a time limit on discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

If I send out a request to a user for them to reply to a yes or no question, how can I make it such that after a certain amount of time, the question expires and is no longer accepting replies?

### Background

I'm currently working on a `discord.py` bot, and I'm getting to the part where I start scanning the messages for user input. How it works is that somebody can challenge someone to a game of tic tac toe, and then the challenged person has 10 seconds to reply with yes or no. How can I make it such that after 10 seconds, the challenge expires?

### Examples

One example I thought of is the bot `Dank Memer`. If you challenge someone to a tic tac toe game on there, then the challenged person has to respond to you within a time limit, or else the challenge expires. It also works with commands like `pls trivia`, where after 10 seconds it stops accepting answers to the question.

**I'm pretty sure that people have already asked this question, but I have looked over and over on Google and I can't find a solution. It's probably because of my wording, I think.**

**It's also hard for me to do a minimal-reproducible example, as that would require you guys to have to create a discord account and token for the bot, which is not at all efficient.**

Comment: Regarding your minimum reproducible example, just include it, it doesn't matter if it requires us to create a bot or an app. your question is regarding code, its better to include the code.

Comment: `Bot.wait_for(...)` has an argument `timeout` which can be used to accomplish this. `Bot.wait_for(timeout=time_in_seconds, ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `bot.wait_for()` with a check and time out.

```
import asyncio

@bot.command()
async def tic_tac_toe(ctx):
    def check(m):
        # returns whether the author of the (input) message is the author of the
        # command and whether the channel of the message is the channel of the command
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

    # asking the question
    await ctx.send("Do you want to play a game of tic tac toe? Respond with yes or no within 10 seconds.")
    
    try:
        # storing the response in a variable, adding the check
        # and setting timeout to 10 seconds (float)
        response = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=10.0)

        if response.content == 'yes':
            # whatever action
        else:
            # whatever action

    # now comes the real part
    except asyncio.TimeOutError:
        await ctx.send("Aw man! You did not respond within ten seconds... try again!")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `await client.wait_for(check=check)`. Check is a function you must define that needs to return either true or false. Within check, you can add various conditions and actions if you need to. I made a command that does a math equation with it, if you'd like to see an example.

Comment: It'd be great if you included the example, thanks!

Comment: @PythonPikachu8, checkout my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66641673/12451222) for info on wait_for.

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried making it myself (good thing I used discord.js before), but for this, I would first prompt the yes/no question, then use sleep() from python's time module, after sleep() has yielded, if there was no response, say that no more responses will be accepted

the general idea is this

```
channels with a prompted question = {}

def prompt question(...):
   display the question
   channels[this channel id] = some function to handle responses for the question

   sleep for N seconds
   
   if this channel id in channels:
      announce in channel that prompt has timed out
      channels.pop(this channel id)

def handle message in a channel(...):
   if channel id in channels:
      channels[channel id](...) # run the prompt's function
```

prompt question() is called when prompting the question in a discord channel
handle message in a channel() is called when a message is received in a channel
and the function you'd insert into the channels dictionary would check if a message is valid for the prompt, handle the response, and pop it from the channels dictionary when it's complete

(sorry, I'm on mobile, so my formate sucks)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try it out (I feel like sleep may be unreliable and may lead to some errors).

Comment: I'm not too familiar with python, but I think the asyncio package is more reliable, just don't do busy waiting, that's horrible in any language lol

Comment: yeah ok, thanks for your advice! so you're saying that the other answer is better?

Comment: I havent used client.wait_for, so I'm not sure if it'll be better to use than sleep()